# Replace text in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have the following sample list of dictionaries and I would like to replace any `.` in the dictionary with a `_`, so the list would look like the list below.

I tried using replace but get the following error:

```py
dict object has no attribute 'replace'
```

if I try something like this:

```py
orig = [
    {
        "health": "good",
        "status": "up",
        "date": "2022.03.10",
        "device.id": "device01"
    },
    {
        "health": "poor",
        "status": "down", 
        "date": "2022.03.10",
        "device.id": "device02"
    }
]
    
length = len(orig)
for i in range(length):
    orig[i].replace(".", "_")
```

Current list:

```py
[
    {
        "health": "good",
        "status": "up",
        "date": "2022.03.10",
        "device.id": "device01"
    },
    {
        "health": "poor",
        "status": "down",
        "date": "2022.03.10",
        "device.id": "device02"
     }
]
```

The new list should look like this:

```py
[
    {
        "health": "good",
        "status": "up",
        "date": "2022_03_10",
        "device_id": "device01"
     },
     {
        "health": "poor",
        "status": "down",
        "date": "2022_03_10",
        "device_id": "device02"
     }
]
```

Comment: `orig[i]` is the `ith` element of the list. It is a dictionary. You want to have some sort of sub-loop to dive into each dictionary.  Alternatively, you might simply use `json.dumps()` to get it all as a string then do the replacement and use `json.loads()` to get back your dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @CryptoFool seems like the one you want. A slightly more blunt force answer might be to just work with strings.

```py
import json
orig= [
    {"health": "good", "status": "up", "date":"2022.03.10","device.id":"device01"},
    {"health": "poor", "status": "down", "date":"2022.03.10","device.id":"device02"}
]
orig_new = json.loads(json.dumps(orig).replace(".","_"))
print(orig_new)
```

That will give you :

```
[
    {'health': 'good', 'status': 'up', 'date': '2022_03_10', 'device_id': 'device01'},
    {'health': 'poor', 'status': 'down', 'date': '2022_03_10', 'device_id': 'device02'}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand how what you're trying would even run.  For the line `orig[i].replace(".", "_")`, `orig[i]` will be a `dict`, and since a `dict` has no `replace()` method, you'll get an error trying to execute this line.

You need to be working on additional level down, operating on each of the key/value pairs in each `dict`.  Here's one solution:

```
orig= [{"health": "good", "status": "up", "date":"2022.03.10","device.id":"device01"}, {"health": "poor", "status": "down", "date":"2022.03.10","device.id":"device02"}]

result = []
for inner_dict in orig:
    new_inner = {}
    for k, v in inner_dict.items():
        new_inner[k.replace('.', '_')] = v.replace('.', '_')
    result.append(new_inner)

print(result)
```

If the keys didn't need to change, it would be simpler (see the other two answers that don't get it right).  You then wouldn't have to create a new structure, but could just work on the values within the existing structure.  But since the keys will also change, it's easiest just to build a new result from scratch, like this shows.

Result:

```
[{'health': 'good', 'status': 'up', 'date': '2022_03_10', 'device_id': 'device01'}, {'health': 'poor', 'status': 'down', 'date': '2022_03_10', 'device_id': 'device02'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
orig = list(map(lambda item: dict((k.replace('.', '_'), v.replace('.', '_')) for k, v in item.items()), orig))
```

The output should be your want.

- Basically, the original data is a `list` of `dict`, and the target is to normalize(replace . -> _) each `key` and `value` in the `dict`.
- So the inner transformation is using a dict() to produce a new `dict` from the original one, `dict((k.replace('.', '_'), v.replace('.', '_')) for k, v in item.items())`
- And for the outer part is a pythonic map operation for iterating a `list`

Actually, @CryptoFool's answer should be more clear for beginners.

Comment: While this is a good answer in that your code produces the correct result, it would be a great answer if you explained it a bit. It is a little dense in my opinion to stand on its own for a beginner to understand.

Comment: From [PEP20, The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): _"Simple is better than complex."_

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to do the trick:

```
def convert(list_dict, old_text, new_text):
    def replace_dict(old_dict, old_text, new_text):
        return {key.replace(old_text, new_text) : val.replace(old_text, new_text) for key, val in old_dict.items()}
        
    for i in range(len(list_dict)):
        list_dict[i] = replace_dict(list_dict[i], old_text, new_text)

orig= [{"health": "good", "status": "up", "date":"2022.03.10","device.id":"device01"}, {"health": "poor", "status": "down", "date":"2022.03.10","device.id":"device02"}]

convert(orig, '.', '-')
print(orig)
```

Basically, it modifies the old dictionary in-place but creates replacement dictionaries for each element.

Comment: You don't seem to "*modify old dictionary in-place*". Your solution seems sound but you construct a new dictionary via a comprehension.

Comment: not sure how to place a thanks to all the different options, but thanks everyone for providing different ways to solve this. I am new to python and this information is definitely helpful.

Comment: @ehink27 If you want to thank someone for a helpful answer, you should click the up arrow just to the upper left.

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate in list of dictionaries or change format:

```
# first solution
new_list_of_dictionaries = []
for dictionary in orig:
    new_dictionary = {}
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        new_dictionary[k.replace(".", "_")] = v.replace(".", "_")
    new_list_of_dictionaries.append(new_dictionary)
orig = new_list_of_dictionaries
# second_solution
import json
orig = json.loads(json.dumps(orig).replace(".", "_"))
```